# POST request with the `request` library in Python so that the body has the required format

Tags: python-requests, http-post

I'm a noob in http requests. 
I need to perform POST request whose body should have the following format: `list[id1]=value1&list[id2]=value2&...`
 with the `request` library in Python.

I've already tried different ways to form data, for example like this:

```
import requests


data = {'list': {'1': '2', '3':'4'}}
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=data)
```

with result:

```
> r.request.body
list=1&list=3
```

How do I get `list[1]=2&list[3]=4`?

Answer (score 0):

What you doing here is sending the data in dict format so this is the result you get for sending that in post request (the dict and its keys)

Try importing the json library and send that as json, e.g:

```
import requests
import json

data = json.dumps({'list': {'1': '2', '3':'4'}})
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=data)
```

result:

```
r.request.body
'{"list": {"1": "2", "3": "4"}}'
```

After that you can parse the json sent received on that post call and get the required keys and values.